# Angular Universal Error: Cannot find module 'XXXXXXX/server/main.js'

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm quite new with angular universal. I have a project which runs fine normally. Now I want to use the server side rendering in.
I have the following setup:

- app.server.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
    import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
    
    import { AppModule } from './app.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule,
        ServerModule,
        ModuleMapLoaderModule
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    })
    export class AppServerModule {}
```

- main.server.ts

```
    import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
    
    import { environment } from './environments/environment';
    
    if (environment.prod) {
      enableProdMode();
    }
    
    export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
    export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

- server.ts

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * Load `$localize` onto the global scope - used if i18n tags appear in Angular templates.
 */
import '@angular/localize/init';
import 'zone.js/node';

// Refrence Error Event Not Found Solution
global['Event'] = null;

// Refrence Error Window Not found  solution
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../', '', 'browser/index.html')).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;

// Refrence Error localStorage Not found  solution
import 'localstorage-polyfill'
global['localStorage'] = localStorage;

const cors = require('cors');

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  server.use(cors());
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/multikart/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';
  const LAZY_MODULE_MAP = require('./src/main.server');
  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
    providers: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  
  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, 
      providers: [{ 
        provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
        useValue: req.baseUrl 
      }]
    });
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

- tsconfig.server.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app-server",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  ,    "target": "es2016"
},
  "files": [
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "./src/app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

PROBLEM: When I run the command `npm run dev:ssr`, I get the following output:

```
> multikart@0.0.0 dev:ssr
> ng run multikart:serve-ssr

Node.js version v15.14.0 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.
****************************************************************************************
This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.
It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!
****************************************************************************************
Option "extractCss" is deprecated: Deprecated since version 11.0. No longer required to disable CSS extraction for HMR.
"BuilderProgressSchema" schema is using the keyword "id" which its support is deprecated. Use "$id" for schema ID.
Warning: Support was requested for IE 11 in the project's browserslist configuration. IE 11 support is deprecated since Angular v12.
For more information, see https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
✔ Server application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files | Names         |      Size
main.js             | main          |   9.84 MB

                    | Initial Total |   9.84 MB

Lazy Chunk Files    | Names         |      Size
677.js              | -             |   2.65 MB
838.js              | -             | 819.46 kB
950.js              | -             | 725.99 kB
467.js              | -             | 534.25 kB
715.js              | -             | 498.13 kB
764.js              | -             | 165.63 kB
521.js              | -             |  15.82 kB

Build at: 2021-11-10T22:39:29.892Z - Hash: 8b86380f38b6116880f8 - Time: 23732ms
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Index html generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files                                                                                            | Names         |      Size
vendor-es2015.js                                                                                               | vendor        |   4.65 MB
styles.css                                                                                                     | styles        | 926.86 kB
main-es2015.js                                                                                                 | main          | 850.46 kB
polyfills-es2015.js                                                                                            | polyfills     | 137.16 kB
scripts.js                                                                                                     | scripts       |  34.65 kB
runtime-es2015.js                                                                                              | runtime       |  11.85 kB

                                                                                                               | Initial Total |   6.56 MB

Lazy Chunk Files                                                                                               | Names         |      Size
src_app_shop_shop_module_ts-es2015.js                                                                          | -             |   3.49 MB
src_app_pages_pages_module_ts-es2015.js                                                                        | -             |   1.19 MB
src_app_home_home_module_ts-es2015.js                                                                          | -             | 531.11 kB
src_app_elements_elements_module_ts-es2015.js                                                                  | -             | 165.94 kB
default-node_modules_angular_cdk___ivy_ngcc___fesm2015_platform_js-src_app_services_email_ser-eda7cd-es2015.js | -             |  20.32 kB
common-es2015.js                                                                                               | common        |   3.68 kB

Build at: 2021-11-10T22:39:33.955Z - Hash: b43142d36903af80c9cf - Time: 23524ms

Compiled successfully.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/XXXXXXXXX/dist/multikart/server/main.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

A server error has occurred.
node exited with 1 code.
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:54133
```

Would you please help me to find the problem and to fix it? I'm struggling with that since days.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi  are you sure you don't have to wait some time (like 1 minute) for the server build process to complete? I have a similar project, and after launching my backend (which is ASP.NET Core) the command `npm run build:ssr` is invoked, and I have to wait for the **dist/server** folder to appear

Comment: Also, check the contents of the `dist` folder. After running `npm run build:ssr`, is the `server` folder being generated somewhere else? This path has already been changed a few times...

Comment: did you find the answer for that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `npm run build:ssr` first to generate a build, then `npm run serve:ssr`

Comment: I did that, and I still get `Error: Cannot find module 'C:\path\to\my-angular-app\dist\my-angular-app\server\main.js'`. After `npm run build:ssr`, there is no `dist/my-angular-app/server` directory, though there is a `dist/my-angular-app/browser` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to double check

- "Server" configuration section in angular.json - Check output path here
- "Package.json" - Check if same path pointed herein "serve:ssr" task

Checkout example [here](https://www.arunyadav.in/blogs/post/26/part2-angular-universal-with-angular-15)

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.